# how do i approach this qpsk filter question

Tags: matlab

Task 1: Change the parameter “Stop time” until you see that convergence of the BER value is achieved. Do this for at least 3 digital modulation techniques, namely QPSK, 8PSK and 8QAM. Once you have shown convergence you will need to use the appropriate value for the “stop Time” for the rest of the coursework.

In Fig.1 plot the BER w.r.t. stop time for QPSK, 8PSK and 8QAM and comment on the results.

my image shows the filter made[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgWHy.png)

i tried running the simulation, and i cant figure out how i should approach the question